# what's the equivalent version of MYISAM for show innodb status in mysql

Tags: mysql

by `Show innodb status` I can see information about deadlock and so on,

but I don't know is there an equivalent version for MYISAM-engine tables?

Answer (score 10):

`show open tables` and `show table status`, though neither is myisam-exclusive, though show table status has more info for myisam tables.

Myisam has only table-level locking and no transactions, so the state of its tables is much simpler.